# verifiction sites google api, error You are not an owner of this site

Tags: php, google-search-console, google-console-developer

I can't do any actions to verify sites by `Google Console api`

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MyAppName");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setAccessType('offline'); 
$client->setAccessToken($token);
$verificationService = new Google_Service_SiteVerification($client);
$verificationService->webResource->get('https://domain.com');
```

Where `domain.com` is my domain adding also by google api
I get error

> "You are not an owner of this site"

Comment: Then you are not passing the correct information to the API

Comment: what kind of information? there is one $client_id and $client_secret

Comment: Don't you need some Google html file placed on site root?

Comment: Don't you have to have at least one verification method setup on the domain you're trying to verify? Just using `Google_Service_SiteVerification` won't verify you're the owner as I could just run `$verificationService->webResource->get('https://stackoverflow.com');` and claim it.

Comment: How can I verify sites on google by using google console api?

Answer (score 0):

now I found how verify sites by file

```
$service = new Google_Service_SiteVerification($client);
$site = new Google_Service_SiteVerification_SiteVerificationWebResourceResourceSite();
$site->setIdentifier('https://domain.com');
$site->setType('SITE');
$request = new Google_Service_SiteVerification_SiteVerificationWebResourceResource();
$request->setSite($site);
$response = $service->webResource->insert('FILE', $request);
```

another question. How to find the verification filename. For example google50c005f8ca59a753.html

Comment: also found it `code`$service = new Google_Service_SiteVerification($client);
     
   $site = new Google_Service_SiteVerification_SiteVerificationWebResourceGettokenRequestSite();
   $site->setIdentifier('https://domain.com');
   $site->setType('SITE');

   $request = new Google_Service_SiteVerification_SiteVerificationWebResourceGettokenRequest();
   $request->setSite($site);
   $request->setVerificationMethod('FILE');

   $webResource = $service->webResource;
   $result = $webResource->getToken($request);`code`